# Qt websockets to connect to Pusher service

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, pusher

I have a javascript snippet that connects to a pusher service that I need to convert to c++

```
<script src="//js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pusher = new Pusher("cb65d0a7a72cd94adf1f");
var channel = pusher.subscribe("ticker.155");
channel.bind("message", function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        var topbuy = data.trade.topbuy;
        var topsell = data.trade.topsell;
        console.log("Buy Price: ", topbuy.price,
                "Buy Quantity:", topbuy.quantity),
        console.log("Sell Price: ", topsell.price,
                "Sell Quantity:", topsell.quantity);
});
</script>
```

I was able to bust open the connection packet to get a little idea of what is going on  https://i.stack.imgur.com/a43xC.png  But I can't seem to get a connection.

socketclass.cpp

```
#include "socketclass.h"

socketClass::socketClass(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void socketClass::Test()
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connected()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), this, SLOT(bytesWritten(qint64)));

    qDebug() << "......Connecting";

    socket->connectToHost("ws.pusherapp.com/app/cb65d0a7a72cd94adf1f?protocol=7&client=js&version=2.2.3&flash=false",80);

    if(!socket->waitForConnected(1000))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error:  "  << socket->errorString();
    }

}

void socketClass::connected()
{
    //meat and potatoes goes here
    qDebug() << "......Connected";
    //socket->write("HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n\r\n");
    socket->event();
}

void socketClass::disconnected()
{
    qDebug() << "......Disconnected";
}

void socketClass::bytesWritten (qint64 bytes)
{
    qDebug() << "We wrote:   " << bytes;
}

void socketClass::readyRead()
{
    qDebug() <<  "Reading..,,";
    qDebug() << socket->readAll();
}
```

socketclass.h

```
#ifndef SOCKETCLASS_H
#define SOCKETCLASS_H
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QAbstractSocket>

class socketClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit socketClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    void Test();

signals:


public slots:
    void connected();
    void disconnected();
    void bytesWritten (qint64 bytes);
    void readyRead();

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;

};

#endif // SOCKETCLASS_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "socketclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    socketClass mTest;
    mTest.Test();

    return a.exec();
}
```

What are the proper connection parameters I should use with c++ websockets to emulate the Javascript?
I am just trying to receive the ticker data and assign it to an object or variable.

Answer (score 0):

My Qt experience is a bit old, but from what I see you won't get the signals since you don't have an event loop running. You should not use the `waitForConnected` call, you should either run the `a.exec()` and let take it care of pumping the events. The only thing that seems weird is that you call the `waitForConnected`, most likely get an an error but still call `a.exec()` 
but don't get the signals after that (or maybe you are stopping the application after the failure?).

Comment: I can't even establish a basic connection. I haven't address error handling yet. Can you explain your response a little more in detail?

Comment: Qt needs a thread to dispatch the signals that you connect your slots to, that is what happens when you call `a.exec()`, Qt internally enters an event loop and starts pumping events. Until you have launched the event loop no signals will be delivered so none of your handlers will be called. That is why suggested removing the 'waitForConnected()` call and checking what happens when you enter the event loop. Event the Qt documentation states `Note: This function may fail randomly on Windows. Consider using the event loop and the connected() signal if your software will run on Windows.`.